# Semantic UI: Make vertical menu (sidebar) collapse in tablet and mobile view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, semantic-ui

I'm building an HTML + CSS design based on Semantic UI and I was able to make pretty much any element responsive by using the class `stackable`.

However the left vertical menu, which I use as a visible sidebar, won't collapse in tablet and mobile view.

The result I need is exactly like the Semantic UI Docs page: the sidebar visible in desktop and landscape tablet and hidden, but toggleable, in portrait tablet and mobile.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="ui left vertical menu collapsible main sidebar visible desktop only">
    <div class="transparent-bg">
        <div class="ui center aligned basic sideheader segment">
            <h2 class="ui header">Dashboard</h2>
        </div>
        <a class="bold item">
            <i class="building outline icon"></i>Add Item
        </a>
        <a class="active item">
          Item 1
        </a>
        <a class="item">
          Item 2
        </a>
        <a class="item">
          Item 3
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea on how I can achieve this? There's no documentation on the official docs page.

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't know about semantic UI, but there are plenty of ways to do this in normal HTML/JS/CSS

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms great, thank you! Since I'm very new to web design, could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: The sidebar would be visible on desktop, but replaced with a button to open it on mobile?

Comment: Yes, on mobile it'd be replaced with an icon button that toggles it.

Comment: This is a start: https://jsfiddle.net/2zb8g3yp ...It isn't fully functioning

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll work on this :)

Comment: You'll just need to add a bit of JavaScript to make the button work. If you need me to do it, I'll gladly help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with semantic-ui but have you checked https://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html ?